# ocp-indent and eliom files

Tags: ocaml, ocsigen, typerex

I installed ocp-indent 1.4.2 via opam. It works fine with most of ocaml files but it fails to indent the eliom files properly. For example the following

```
{shared{
  open Eliom_lib
}}
```

is indented as

```
{shared{
open Eliom_lib
}}
```

The command ocp-indent --print-config gives

```
base = 2
type = 2
in = 0
with = 0
match_clause = 2
ppx_stritem_ext = 2
max_indent = 2
strict_with = never
strict_else = always
strict_comments = false
align_ops = true
align_params = auto
syntax = mll lwt
```

Is the configuration wrong?

Comment: Send the maintainer a formal issue report or give us more to work with. This place is not a random issue tracker.

Comment: @romainl Sorry this is not related to vim. The maintainers of typerex ask for posting questions here.